# Given only P(A), P(A or B), and P(B|A), can P(~A and B) be calculated?

Tags: probability, statistics

I know only the values for P(A), P(A or B) and P(B|A). It is not known what events A and B correspond to. It is also not known that ~A and B are independent so P(~A and B) can't be calculated via P(~A) * P(B). I don't think ~A and B are independent since after determining P(B) and P(A and B), I determined A and B are not independent events since P(A) * P(B) does not equal P(A and B). I've seen that A, B are independent iff A, ~B; ~A, B; ~A, ~B are also independent pairs of events (see http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~olshen/hrp261win03/win03handouts/handout010803.pdf) which would mean that if A and B aren't independent, then ~A and B aren't independent. However, I've only seen the forward direction of this iff (or bi-implication) statement proven. Not the other direction which is needed to prove an iff statement. Maybe I'm missing something, but assuming ~A and B are in fact independent, can P(~A and B) be calculated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A or B) is the disjoint union of events (A) and (~A and B), so

P(~A and B) = P(A or B) - P(A)